# What's wrong with this maximum-minimum batch code?

Tags: batch-file

I wrote this code to see how wide the range of batch random numbers is.

It simply uses two maximum and minimum variables which are updated.

But the Maximum is always less than the Minimum. why?

```
@echo off
color 0A

set /a max = 0
set /a min = 40000

:start
cls
set /a key = %random% 

if "%key%" LSS "%min%" (
set /a min = %key%
)
if "%key%" GTR "%max%" (
set /a max = %key%
)

echo max: %max%
echo min: %min%

goto start
```

Comment: @wOxxOm. sorry. I didn't get it.

Comment: If you want to compare _numbers_, do NOT enclose they in quotes. However, if you want to know "how wide the range of batch random numbers is", you may read the help of `set` command: "%RANDOM% - expands to a random decimal number between 0 and 32767"

Comment: @Aacini, I think you are right.  I can't get the max to max out.  I can get the min down to 0 but after 5 minutes, my max is holding at 9999. If I take out the quotes it will get to the min and max in about 2 minutes in all of my tests.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My shortened version. I put the min and max in the TITLE because the flicker kills my eyes.

```
@echo off

set /a max=0
set /a min=32767
echo %time%
:start
TITLE Min:%min% Max:%max%
set key=%random%
if %key% LSS %min% set min=%key%
if %key% GTR %max% set max=%key%
IF NOT %min%%max%==032767 goto start
echo %time%
pause
```

Comment: Why haven't you put an "/a" before the key variable?

Comment: @BlueSky not needed. Not needed on your other set statenents either. You are technically not doing any arithmetic operation so it is not required.